# Showing that $B=\{x \in F \mid \text{ the sequence $(f_k(x))_{k \in \Bbb N}$ is increasing} \}$ is measurable.

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $F \subset \Bbb R$ be Lebesgue measurable set and $f_k : F \to \Bbb R$ measurable functions for every $k \in \Bbb N$. Show that $F_k=\{x \in F \mid f_{k+1}(x) \ge f_{k}(x) \}$ is measurable and furthermore show that $B=\{x \in F \mid \text{ the sequence $(f_k(x))_{k \in \Bbb N}$ is increasing} \}$ is measurable.

The set $F_k$ can be expressed as $F_k = \{x \in F \mid f_{k+1}(x) -f_{k}(x)\ge0 \} $ now this is the preimage of some sequence of functions $h_k(x) = f_{k+1}(x) -f_{k}(x) $ so $F_k = h_k^{-1}((0, \infty))$ but $h_k$ is measurable since $f_{k+1} $ and $f_k$ are measurable so $F_k$ is measurable.

My question is that isn’t the second question the exact same? If $(f_k(x))_{k \in \Bbb N} $ is increasing then $f_{k+1}(x) - f_k(x) \ge 0$ for all $k \in \Bbb N$ so the set $$B=\{x \in F \mid \text{ the sequence $(f_k(x))_{k \in \Bbb N}$ is increasing} \} = F_k$$ which is measurable?

Answer (score 1):

I think $B$ and $F_k$ should not be the same in general:
$$\begin{aligned}\{x \in F: (f_k(x))_{k \in \mathbb{N}}\textrm{ is increasing}\}&=\{x \in F: f_{k+1}(x)\geq f_k(x),\,\forall k \in \mathbb{N}\}=\\
&=\bigcap_{k \in \mathbb{N}}\{x \in F: f_{k+1}(x)\geq f_k(x)\}\end{aligned}$$
so actually $B\subseteq F_k,\forall k \in \mathbb{N}$. The countable intersection of measurable sets is measurable, so the set $B$ is measurable.

Comment: What’s the difference between $B$ and $F_k$? Are the maps $f_{k+1}$ and $f_k$ fixed in $F_k$ and in $B$ we’re considering all maps?

Comment: @JimingLe Yes in $F_k$ we just consider $f_k$ and $f_{k+1}$, while in $B$ we consider them all